# Does a projectile always meet a freely falling body when aimed at it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

When we aim a projectile at a freely falling body why does it always meet it irrespective of the range and speed.

Comment: How good a marksman are you that you've never missed before? I'm impressed, but if this were the case, skeet shooting would not be much of a challenge and I'd bet no one would partake in it

Comment: You obviously have a specific situation in mind because shooting down objects in ballistic trajectories is generally exceedingly hard - in practice projectiles generally miss freely falling bodies. Can you edit your question to explain exactly what ituation you're asking about.

Comment: this is explained in Walter Lewin's series of lectures from MIT OpenCourseWare. Here is a sample of the relevant part https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEwrshYWs. Unfortunately I don't remember the exact lecture :(

Comment: The experiment is called _The Monkey and the Hunter_ or _Shoot the Monkey._ See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_and_the_Hunter) Wikipedia page and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jGZnMf3rPo) Youtube video.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. It's only when the projectile and freely falling body are released from rest at the exact same time, and the effects of air resistance are roughly equal on both of them (feather aimed at a cannonball, not so much).

And that's simply because gravity affects them the same. Its analogous to how a car going 70mph looks like a car going 0 mph when you're looking out your car window at 70mph. That's why it's sometimes helpful (and not the only reason) to picture gravity as bending "space itself" (making a straight line between the projectile and falling body) rather than just being a force.

Comment: So you mean to say that both reach the ground the same time.what if the the speed was so low that the project tile can't even make it to the object. Does this thing still works

Comment: No that doesn't mean they both reach the ground at the same time, because the projectile could be pointed up. If the speed is so low that the projectile can't even make it to the object, then no, it won't make it to the object.

Comment: Can there be a case when the speed is so high that the projectile misses the object?

Comment: @tapadianewlon no. The higher the speed, the more likely it will hit exactly what it's aimed at (assuming calibrated sights and no external factors like drag or a bird)

Comment: The conditions are not quite as restrictive a this.  If the target has been freely falling, and you observe it falling at some velocity, and fire a projectile with the correct lead, assuming constant velocities for both target and projectile, you'll still hit.  The two erroneous assumptions cancel out...